# Heroku express app, post request returns application error

Tags: javascript, express

First time deploying my app using heroku.
The app works fine on get requests but trying to do POST request with body the app sending application error.

checked the logs on heroku and there seem to be a problem with mongodb authintication. BUT if I ran the code locally it does work. I have to mention that I did enable access to any IP using 0.0.0.0/0

Setting up the header of app.use like this (I found this solution online):

```js
app.use((req, res) => {
    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
})
```

Here it the POST request on the express app:

```js
app.post('/newOrder', async (req, res) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *')
    const { fullname, phone, textMsg, currentItems, total } = req.body
    let message = []
    let inputType = []

    if (fullname.length === 0) {
        const errMsg = 'שדה זה לא יכול להיות ריק'
        message.push(errMsg)
        inputType.push(0)
    }

    if (phone.length === 0) {
        const errMsg = 'שדה זה לא יכול להיות ריק'
        message.push(errMsg)
        inputType.push(1)
    }

    if (!(/^[a-zA-Z\u0590-\u05FF\s]+$/.test(fullname))) {
        const errMsg = 'שם מלא חייב להכיל אותיות ורווחים בלבד'
        message.push(errMsg)
        inputType.push(0)
    }
    if (!(/^[0-9]+$/).test(phone)) {
        const errMsg = 'מספר הטלפון חייב להכיל מספרים בלבד'
        message.push(errMsg)
        inputType.push(1)
    }

    if (textMsg.length > 0) {
        if (!(/^[a-zA-Z0-9,:-\u0590-\u05FF\s]+$/.test(textMsg))) {
            const errMsg = 'הודעה למעצב צריכה להכיל רק אותיות, רווחים ומספרים בלבד'
            message.push(errMsg)
            inputType.push(2)
        }
    }


    if (inputType.length !== 0) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            message,
            inputType
        })
    }

    const newTicket = new Ticket({
        fullname,
        phone,
        textMsg,
        items: currentItems.map((data) => data.desc),
        total
    })
    await newTicket.save()
        .then(async (order) => {
            const isMailSent = await mailTicket(fullname, phone, textMsg, currentItems, total, order)
            if (!isMailSent) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    mailError: true,
                    message: 'תקלה זמנית בשליחת ההזמנה למעצב - ניתן לפנות ישירות למעצב'
                })
            }
            return res.status(200).json({
                orderId: order._id
            })
        })
})
```

what could be the problem?

Comment: "the app sending application error" — What error does it send? Why do you think it has anything to do with CORS?

Comment: There was a cors error when the api worked but now I see in logs that there is a problem connecting to mongodb.
though if I run app.js locally it works, and I did enable access to 0.0.0.0/0 anywhere on mognodb

Comment: I found the problem, the auth user and password are stored in .env and I had .gitignoe and that .env BUT even though I did push it to heroku the pass and username from .env were undefined so I declared them directly on app.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now:

1. .env file was ignored
2. therefore DB wasn't connected

Managed to fix it by pushing changes to heroku without .env vars, stating the credentials explicitly in app.js

[How to set .env variables on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)